# Get segmentedcontrol value from tableviewcells

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, ios7, uisegmentedcontrol

How do i get the value (the selected state) from my segmentedcontrols in the tableviewcells?
When i press the button "Get states" it should return the value for each of the segmented controls. I have tried different methods, but I can't find one that works :(

My code so far:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"First", @"Second", @"Third", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"StateCell"];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"StateCell"];
}

//Config cell..
cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(110, 7, 100, 28);

[cell.contentView addSubview:segmentedControl];

return cell;
[[self tableView] reloadData];
}

- (IBAction)getStates:(id)sender {

// Ruturn the current selected statement, for the individual cell's segmentedcontrol..
// Ex. First = SelectedState 1, Second = SelectedState 0 & Third = SelectedState 2..

}
```

**So what I'm really is asking for; is what the "Get states" button action has to do..**

Thanks for your time!

[image: Screenshot of what i mean..]

Comment: Have you made an attempt at this yourself? Or are you just asking for code?

Comment: Hi.
I have been trying all kinds of methods..
So code would be very nice!

I am only 15, and I'm pretty new to IOS development ;)

Comment: Please add the code that you've tried to your question and explain in detail what specific part you're stuck on and what's going wrong.

Comment: The last methods I have found have been full of errors and outdated code :( It would help me a lot if you would help me move on with my project! :) Thanks

Comment: You need to add the relevant code to the question, otherwise we can't help you. We need to see what you are doing wrong before we can tell you what to fix.

Comment: Im stuck at what code need to be in the "Get states" action. The project can be downloaded here: http://www.mediafire.com/download/62mqbu8d54k17nd/GetIndexTest.zip

Comment: Question has been updated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a couple of problems. Most of them happen because a UITableView reuses its cells.

You are creating a new UISegmentedControl each time a cell is displayed, which you should not. You should create the UISegmentedControl only if you create the cell, move that code into the `cell == nil)`.

You don't have a dataSource that saves the state of the segments. You should not save states in views, especially not if you are dealing with a tableView, because cells are reused.

Here's an example that will get the functionality you need.

```
// this is an object of your model, it has a title and saves the selected index
@interface MBFancyObject : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *title;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger selectedIndex;
@end

@implementation MBFancyObject
@end


@interface MasterViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_objects;     // stores instances of MBFancyObject
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // set up the model
    _objects = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        MBFancyObject *object = [[MBFancyObject alloc] init];
        object.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Object #%ld", (long)i];
        object.selectedIndex = i % 3;
        [_objects addObject:object];
    }

    UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Get States" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(logStates:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _objects.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FancyCell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"FancyCell"];
        // add the segmentedControl when you create a new cell
        UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"1", @"2", @"3"]];
        segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(110, 7, 100, 28);
        [cell.contentView addSubview:segmentedControl];

        // add an action so we can change our model if the view changes
        [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(didChangeSegmentedControl:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        // use a tag so we can retrieve the segmentedControl later
        segmentedControl.tag = 42;
    }
    // either if the cell could be dequeued or you created a new cell,
    // segmentedControl will contain a valid instance 
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:42];

    MBFancyObject *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = object.title;
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = object.selectedIndex;
    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)didChangeSegmentedControl:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    // transform the origin of the cell to the frame of the tableView
    CGPoint senderOriginInTableView = [self.tableView convertPoint:CGPointZero fromView:sender];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:senderOriginInTableView];
    NSAssert(indexPath, @"must have a valid indexPath");
    MBFancyObject *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
    object.selectedIndex = sender.selectedSegmentIndex;
}

- (IBAction)logStates:(id)sender {
    // query the model, not the view
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [_objects count]; i++) {
        MBFancyObject *object = _objects[i];
        NSLog(@"Object \"%@\" - %ld", object.title, (long)object.selectedIndex);

        // since you have only one section, each indexPath is 0,i
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I cannot figure out how to define new cells, other than "Object #7" and so on. What if I wanted 20 cells, with names like Dog, Cat, Horse... Hope u still want to help me! The code I'm talking about is under - (void)viewDidLoad :)

Comment: remove the `for` loop in `viewDidLoad` and create a `MBFancyObject` for each row manually. Or keep the for loop and get the animal strings from an array so you can replace the stringWithFormat: thingie.

Comment: Thank for the fast answer! I think the method with the strings in an array would be the best, and keep the loop ;) When you say "or keep the for loop and get the animal strings from an array so you can replace the stringWithFormat: thingie" it sounds very easy, but for a guy like me, 15 years old, and no education in app development yet, it can be hard! :P I will keep trying, but if you can give me an example how to do it = AMAZING!! :D THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Use an array to store all the segment control values, and when click one segment control then just change the value correspondingly.

Answer (score 0):

You have serious problem with reusing here

Do not ever allocate a new UI element in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method unless it is in the if condition `if (cell == nil)`

Change What in Your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to be

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"StateCell"];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"StateCell"];

    // Add the Segmented Control
    NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(110, 7, 100, 28);
    segmentedControl.tag = 1;
    [cell addSubview:segmentedControl];
}

//Config cell..
cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// Get that Segmented Control
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0; // Set your default value here or add your data in an array and read from that array

return cell;
```

Then in the action of the button do that

```
for (UITableViewCell *cell in [tableView visibleCells]) {
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    NSLog(@"%d",segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex);
}
```

However this code is not perfect unless you have only 3 cells in your table to avoid reuse or visibility problem